# Kubernetes and microk8s join error: Joining failed

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, devops, kubectl, microk8s

I am trying to learn microk8s. I installed 3 Ubuntu in my virtual box. I installed the microk8s on each of these virtual machines. I want machines in the form of master node and 2 worker nodes to communicate with each other. I tried to use

```
microk8s add-node
```

command in first machine. And in the second machine, I tried to join this as a worker. But it does not work. I gave this error:

```
microk8s join 10.0.2.15:25000/<>/<> --worker

Connecting cluster at 10.0.2.15
Joining cluster failed. Could not verify the identity of 10.0.2.15. User '--skip-verify' to skip server certificate check.
```

If I tried to `microk8s join --skip-verify 10.0.2.15:25000/<>/<> --worker` I got an error which is

> Connection failed. Invalid token (500).

How could I join the node from second virtual machine? Could you help me? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: May be its a network issue. worker nodes are not able to communicate with master node or vice varsa